# How can i apply transition on hover on a div or stack ( chakra ui)

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, css-transitions, chakra-ui

Why transition is not applying on mouseenter and mouseleave.Stack is going up to -10px on mouse enter but transition is not working

here the code is:

```
 const Card = () => {
        
            const [isHovering, setHovering] = useState('')
        
            function handleMouseEnter() {
        
                setHovering(true)
        
            }
            function handleMouseLeave() {
        
                setHovering(false)
        
            }
        
        
            return (
        
                <Stack
                    style={{
                        position: 'relative',
                        top: 0,
                        top: isHovering ? '-10px' : '',
                        transition: isHovering ? 'top ease 0.5s' : ''
        
                    }}
                    onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave} >
</Stack>

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you remove transition on mouse leave `transition: isHovering ? 'top ease 0.5s' : ''`, try this

```
style={{
    position: 'relative',
    top: isHovering ? '-10px' : '0px',
    transition: 'top ease 0.5s',
}}
```

Comment: yes i try this but still it is not working

Comment: @sohaib i have updated my answer, you have to remove your default top position

Comment: The default position has no concern with the transition here. The issue was in condition of  isHovering. It works now.